# How to direct contact form submission to a certain page

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7, contact

I have a contact form in wordpress that has an income field which is a drop down. The options are 0-R9999 and R10000+. I have 2 thank you pages. I would like the form to go to a certain thank you page depending on the selection that was made in the drop down.

Any help?

Comment: Third party plugins are [off-topic here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please consult the support forum.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with paying for a plugin, here's one that does exactly what you need:
https://querysol.com/product/contact-form-7-redirection/

Otherwise you need to write some code yourself, the documentation is here:
https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/

The code itself needs to be extended a bit, e.g.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if (jQuery('#yourdropdown').val() == '0') {
        location = 'http://example1.com/';
    } if (jQuery('#yourdropdown').val() == 'R9999') {
        location = 'http://example2.com/';
    }
}, false );
</script>
```